# getting value from JSON in iPhone through JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, iphone, google-maps, ios4, mapkit

I am building an application to find the route between two places.Also, i have to give the details of checkpoint between the route.In this case, I'm struggling. Through JSON i got the different checkpoint like this

```
    "<b>NH 75</b>\U3092\U9032\U3080<div class=\"google_note\">\n<b landmarkid=\"0x39847e91e9351f85:0x9e82c70b4b91c047\" class=\"dir-landmark\">\U30da\U30c8\U30ed\U30fc\U30eb\U30fb\U30d1\U30f3\U30d7</b>\U3092\U901a\U904e\U3059\U308b<div class=\"dirseg-sub\">\Uff0831.0&nbsp;km \U5148\U3001\U5de6\U624b\Uff09</div>\n</div>"
"\U5de6\U6298\U3057\U3066<b>SH 11</b>\U306b\U5165\U308b"
"1 \U3064\U76ee\U306e\U89d2\U3092\U53f3\U306b\U66f2\U304c\U3063\U3066\U3001\U305d\U306e\U307e\U307e<b>SH 11</b>\U3092\U9032\U3080<div class=\"google_note\">\n<b landmarkid=\"0x39847f74faa9a325:0xd74f16593a886b60\" class=\"dir-landmark\">Prem Nursing Home</b><div class=\"dirseg-sub\">\Uff08\U53f3\U5074\Uff09</div>\U3092\U901a\U904e\U3059\U308b</div>"
```

for this, i have to print value like this....

```
1. Continue onto NH 75
    Pass by Petrol Pump (on the left in 31.0 km)

2. Turn left onto SH 11

3. Take the 1st right
    to stay on SH 11
    Pass by Prem Nursing Home (on the right)
```

I'm getting place name.But, in fetching details m struggling. How can it be done.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanx in advance.

Comment: That isn't JSON.  I think you can get JSON with the API, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString%3a) has the method **- stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:** - this should help with your issue.

Example:

```
NSString *result = [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"someJavascriptFunction(42);"];
```

Comment: Lol, omg yes. I should keep an eye on post dates :) But it's good to know I am on the right track with my work!

Comment: For that thing only, I’m accepting this as an answer.Anyways, thnx for ur answer. This will definitely help others.